# Matlab : find x points with same distance

Tags: matlab

I want to plot some number of random circles, separated by distances of between 3 and 25.

So, if the radius of each circle is 5, the distances between their centres must be between 13 and 35.

Here is my current code, but doesn't work :

```
ok=false;
while 1
    x = 100 * rand(100,1);
    y = 100 * rand(100,1);
    A = pdist2([x,y],[x,y]);
    test1 = (A > 3 + size*num_clusters);
    test2 = A < 30 + size*num_clusters;
    test3 = test1.*test2;
    num_clusters = 3;
    for i=1:length(x)
        sum(test3(i,:))
        if sum(test3(i,:)) > num_clusters
            logic = test3(i,:);
            logic = find(logic);
            logic = logic';
            x = x(logic);
            y = y(logic);
            ok=true;
            break
        end
        if ok
            break
        end
    end
    if ok
        break
    end
end

X(1:num_clusters,1) = x(1:num_clusters);
X(1:num_clusters,2) = y(1:num_clusters);
```

Comment: If the radius of each circle is 5, you should have them separated by 5( radius circle left) + 5 (radius circle right) + 3 (minimum Distance) = 13, not 8. Did I get what you want?

Comment: Yes it is rigth !

Comment: Specify why "it does not work". There are obvious programming errors (size without argument, num_cluster called before created, etc..). Did you copy paste this code and you need it working, or the code runs but there are conceptual problems in the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

That´s a slightly different take to your solution, but it works nicely. You can just run it in matlab as it is and see the results. let me know

```
   patchCircle = @(diam,X,Y,spec) arrayfun(@(x,y) patch(sin(-pi:.1:pi).*diam +x,cos(-pi:.1:pi).*diam+y,spec{:}),X,Y); % patches a circle of diameter DIAM, centered in x,y

radius_circles                 = 2; 
min_distance_between_circles   = 8; 
max_idstance_between_circles   = 30;
num_circles                    = 6; 
size_area                      = 40; % size of the area where the circles are
maximumNumberOfIterations      = 1000; % maximum mumber of iterations to find each new circle
exitSearch = false;

circles = size_area * rand(1,2);
for i_circle = 1 : num_circles - 1
    j = 1;
    keepLooping = true;
    while keepLooping
        j = j+1;
        if j > maximumNumberOfIterations
            fprintf('maximumNumberOfIterations reached. Increase area size or dicrease number of circles\n');
            keepLooping = false;
            exitSearch = true;
        end
        newCoords = size_area * rand(1,2);
        distances = pdist2(circles,newCoords);
        isMoreThanMinSize = distances > (min_distance_between_circles + radius_circles*2);
        isLessThanMaxSize = distances < (max_idstance_between_circles + radius_circles*2);
        if all(isMoreThanMinSize & isLessThanMaxSize)
            keepLooping = false;
            circles(i_circle,:) = newCoords;
            fprintf('circle n° %d of %d found\n',i_circle+1,num_circles)
        end
    end
    if exitSearch
       break 
    end
end
%% PLOT RESULTS
    cla; patchCircle(radius_circles,circles(:,1),circles(:,2),{'r','facealpha',.2})
    ylim([0 size_area]+[-1 1]*radius_circles)
    xlim([0 size_area]+[-1 1]*radius_circles)
```

Obviously, if you are looking for too many circles, or to big ones, in a space which is too small, the search stops after a certain number of iterations.